# ASP.NET MVC parameter binding: How to POST a list or array to a controller method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, post, forms

I can't seem to figure out how to pass an array of GUIDs as a parameter to a ASP.NET MVC controller via POST.  What am I missing?  Is there a simpler way to do this?

In my AngularJS markup:

```
<form method="post" action="/Foo/Bar" >
  <input name="itemIds" type="hidden" value="{{ ctrl.itemIds }}">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Which results in HTML:

```
<form method="post" action="/Foo/Bar" >
  <input name="itemIds" type="hidden" value="[&quot;8cd52539-c371-402a-b8be-12775f03ab68&quot;,&quot;8c97f9e0-666c-41ba-a914-72815745d1f0&quot;]">
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

In my FooController:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Bar([FromBody]Guid[] itemIds) => ...
```

When I debug the above, my HTTP POST seems to be correct but I get null `itemIds` in `Bar`.  Can you help me change this to work?  Is there a better way to populate my request body, given that I already have an array of GUIDs in my JS model?

Comment: I believe the `Guid` would come across as a `string`, then you would cast into a `Guid`.  For some odd reason, it usually doesn't safely cast the type when you use the default MVC parameters like you have above.

Comment: That makes me sad. Changing the parameter to a string instead of Guid[] results in a single string with backslashes, brackets, and commas in it, which is even worse.  Any ideas of a more elegant way--at least one where I can get a string array or list rather than a single string?

Comment: You could create a basic Json Object, then pass that.  With a single deserialize, to avoid some of the crazy encoding. `{ Id = '' }` type of object, a basic object with an Id property.  Obviously valid Json would help.

Comment: If you want to do a form post and have it bind to an array you usually have to create multiple input fields, one for each element of the array, but with the same `name` property.  So like `<input id="item1" type="hidden" name="itemIds" value="{firstGuid}"/><input id="item2" type="hidden" name="itemIds" value="{secondGuid}"/>`  When it posts up they then will marshal together into an array.

Comment: I was afraid of that. Is there any way to do a non-AJAX POST (that is, in the browser interactively, not returning a value to my JS code) by just providing the data for the body?

Comment: @Greg how does one pass a JSON object as the body in a non-Ajax context?

Comment: @PatrickSzalapski Why can't you use the default `FormCollection`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what's really happening:

`itemIds` is being posted as one single string to the controller. Why? Because `itemIds` is not interpreted as an array. If you want an array, you need to have multiple hidden values named `itemIds[0]`, `itemsIds[1]` and so on. Here is a quick test to prove that what I am saying is actually what is happening:

Create a form like this. See we create one hidden value named `itemIdsOld` and then 2 more hidden values named `itemIds[0]` and `itemIds[1]`:

```
<form method="post" action="/Foo/Bar">
    <input name="itemIdsOld" type="hidden" value="[&quot;f8b21933-419c-4bdd-b5b6-75295ff65612&quot;,&quot;67bb1d75-ae78-49e4-bc29-ee82a51bb9a1&quot;]">
    <input name="itemIds[0]" type="hidden" value="f8b21933-419c-4bdd-b5b6-75295ff65612">
    <input name="itemIds[1]" type="hidden" value="67bb1d75-ae78-49e4-bc29-ee82a51bb9a1">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Create a controller like this:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(string[] itemIdsOld, Guid[] itemIds)
{
    return null;
}
```

When you post the above form, you will notice that a single string is created in `itemIdsOld` and it will have both the Guids in it as a `string`. However, the second one, since we created controls named `itemIds[0]` and `itemIds[1]` will be converted to a `Guid[] itemIds` as you expected.

I am not sure how to do this in Angular, but with C# and Razor, one way to do it would be like this:

```
@using System.Collections.Generic
@{ 
    var guids = new List<Guid> { Guid.NewGuid(), Guid.NewGuid() };
}
<form method="post" action="/Test/Index">
    <input name="itemIdsOld" type="hidden" value="[&quot;f8b21933-419c-4bdd-b5b6-75295ff65612&quot;,&quot;67bb1d75-ae78-49e4-bc29-ee82a51bb9a1&quot;]">
    @{
        for (int i = 0; i < guids.Count; i++)
        {
            <input name="itemIds[@i]" type="hidden" value="@guids[i]">
        }
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

I hard coded the guids but you can get this from a model...you get the point.

---

Alternatively, you can use Javascript to intercept the form submission and retrieve the value from `itemIds` and turn it into an array and submit that to the controller, that would work too.

Comment: Yes. I can use a ng-repeat to do that with Angular, thanks--that may be the best way. Is there any way you can think of to do a POST and just supply the JSON body instead of going thorough hidden form fields?

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean by JSON body instead of going through hidden form fields.

Comment: It seems like a Rube Goldberg machine to set up hidden form fields via AngularJS so that I can POST when I have all the data I need in my Javascript code state to do the POST.  If this were AJAX, I'd just create the AJAX request and be done, but I gather there is no way to create a non-AJAX POST request from Javascript code.